# How to make circle in flutter that has radius of screen height, and sides are clipped?

Tags: flutter

Here is my code for the circle:

```
class Light extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UnconstrainedBox(
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            gradient: RadialGradient(
                center: Alignment.center,
                colors: [Colors.yellow, Colors.black])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Right now the circle has radius of `screenWidth`.
I can make the correct size by wrapping the Light in `UnconstrainedBox` but then I get overflow warning.

Any tips?

Comment: While not a answer to how to fix your code. I would go about it a different way. Create a stack. Then you can use the ClipRect on a widget(CustomPaint). Because you are using box decoration you can't use clip rect though.

Comment: I want to use a gradient for a light effect. So how to go about that

Comment: You will need to do some custom drawing code. This might be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225628/arc-gradients-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hacky way of doing it using mostly the same code you already have. Because it uses a scale factor it won't be exactly aligned to the edge of the circle. However it occurs to me that Maybe you don't care about that. If you like it then please accept it as an answer. If the alignment is an issue I will withdraw it.

```
class Light extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: 3,
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              gradient: RadialGradient(
                  center: Alignment.center,
                  colors: [Colors.yellow, Colors.black])),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that result using a ListView.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final sizeWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final sizeheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: sizeWidth / 2.5),
      children: <Widget>[
        UnconstrainedBox(
          child: Container(
            height: sizeheight,
            width: sizeheight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              gradient: RadialGradient(
                center: Alignment.center,
                colors: [Colors.yellow, Colors.black],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```