# Use Gradient with Paint object in Flutter Canvas

Tags: flutter, canvas, flutter-layout, flutter-canvas

I am able to draw a semi circle using the following example:
[Flutter how to draw semicircle (half circle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748469/flutter-how-to-draw-semicircle-half-circle)

However, the `Paint` object only seems to accept a `Color` (using `Paint.color`). I would like to add a `RadialGradient` or `LinearGradient` as the `Color`. Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arc gradients in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225628/arc-gradients-in-flutter)

Comment: I did see that. I am trying to see if we can add a ```LinearGradient``` using the link shared in the question.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes! This is totally possible using [`Paint.shader`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint/shader.html).
You can either create a gradient shader directly using `dart:ui` or convert a Flutter gradient to a shader using [`Gradient.createShader`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Gradient/createShader.html).

#### [`dart:ui` gradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Gradient-class.html)

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

// In your paint method
final paint = Paint()
  ..shader = ui.Gradient.linear(
    startOffset,
    endOffset,
    [
      color1,
      color2,
    ],
  );
```

A real world example can be [seen here](https://github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/clock/blob/2ef01ffb6187e7a6788051c3b12c73845a90e8fc/canvas_clock/lib/components/style/slide.dart#L375).

#### [Flutter `painting` gradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Gradient-class.html)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

// In your paint method
final paint = Paint()
  ..shader = RadialGradient(
    colors: [
      color1,
      color2,
    ],
  ).createShader(Rect.fromCircle(
    center: offset,
    radius: radius,
  ));
```

An example of this can be [found here](https://github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/clock/blob/92000ef8f59bae8298fb29ec60db42cc0cf6a118/canvas_clock/lib/components/style/ball.dart#L371).

---

These two are effectively the same. The Flutter painting version simply converts it to a `dart:ui` gradient (**shader**) when you call `createShader`. The reason it exists is that the painting version is better suited for prebuilt widgets like `Container`.

Comment: The Flutter ```Paint``` version worked like a charm! Thank you very much!