# How can I create fading hexagon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-canvas

[Fading hexagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgIwi.jpg)

Hello, I want to create and Fading hexagon like in image with a fading purple circle middle on it. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by drawing a radial gradient as shown in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019684/use-gradient-with-paint-object-in-flutter-canvas). Then your colors will be purple and transparent (or purple with an opacity set to 0).
Then you have two possibilities, either you use a big rectangle as a mask for your gradient, either you draw two triangles over your gradient, one at each corner to create that masking effect.

Hope it helped and have a nice day